# how can my code print only one character uppercase in a list

Tags: python, error-handling

```
three_words = ["Ant", "Run", "Worm"]
print(three_words)

three_words[0].upper()
three_words[2].swapcase()

print(three_words)
```

## With the code like this it prints the following

```
#['Ant', 'Run', 'Worm']
['Ant', 'Run', 'Worm']
```

I understand that the upper and swapcase function arent being read but I dont know why

Comment: You need to assign the results. For example, try `three_words[0] = three_words[0].upper()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
three_words = ["Ant", "Run", "Worm"]
print(three_words)

three_words[0] = three_words[0].upper()  # change the value in list
three_words[2] = three_words[2].swapcase()  # change the value in list

print(three_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

The results are not assigned. So, you can call a function on variable, but if you don't assign the result of the function to a variable, then the function did the work, but it was not saved.

So for instance, you would want to assign `three_words[0]= three_words[0].upper()` and `three_words[2] = three_words[2].swapcase()`